# python nested for loop zip

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following list:

```
grid = [[0] *50 for n in range(50)]
```

I want to replace the values in grid (with 1) for each coordinate contained in the list:

```
area = [(30, 28), (27, 32), (32, 34), (43,23), (43, 2) ...] # Continues on
```

Is there any simple method that this can be done?

Comment: Your input is a 50x50 2D list, and your output is of an unknown dimension from what I see from here, can you explain on how you want to convert this

Comment: Hi Davesh. For example the value at grid[30][28] would be changed

Comment: And you have the values to which it will be changed to as well?, also what kind of coordinate is `(43)` or `(23)` ?

Comment: I want to change all values in the list area to 1.

Comment: Lets add all those details in the question as well

Comment: Sure. (43) and (23) were typos. They were meant to be one x, y co-ordinate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple for loop is what is needed.

```
for i,j in area:
    grid[i][j] = 1
```